# Java Web application Charts

Tags: java

I am new to java. I am doing small project  on Jsp and servlet.backend database is MySQL.I am just trying dynamic charts using Jqplot with Jsp and Servlet. I searched in many sites. I couldn't get the correct solution.Anyone please guide me how to do dynamic charts in Jsp and Servlet using jqplot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're missing a comma at line 423, says my crystal ball.

Answer (score 0):

Jqplot is itself contains good example. You can get reference from there as well.

http://www.jqplot.com/tests/

Here is another reference link with complete example which shows how to plot real time data on chart.

http://www.meccanismocomplesso.org/en/jqplot-real-time-data/

Hope this helps you